# How to turn off all auto correct/auto complete features in codeblocks?

Tags: c++, c, ide, codeblocks, turbo-c++

My teacher suggested me to use turbo C at beginner level instead of codeblocks. The reason he said was Codeblocks automatically completes some lines or corrects it (like it automatically sets the spaces in main function, automatically places 'bracket close' etc. ) which turbo C++/turbo c doesn't. It gives benefit for pro programmer but it is bad for the learners. So how to disable all features of this kind?

Comment: _Settings→Editor_ . On the very first page ( _General Settings→Editor Settings_ ) turn off everything. You can try other pages if you find something still helping you. BTW: Turbo C/C++ is an abomination without any relation to real modern C/C++. Never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Plugins and turn off Code completion.